# Which senses of "announce" and "indicate" are most appropriate here?

Tags: differences, meaning

> In tournament play, the chair umpire announces the end of the match with the well-known phrase "Game, set, match" followed by the winning person's or team's name.
>
> It is similarly used in other contexts to indicate the winner, often in an argument or a comparison.

The following definitions are from OALD. Which senses of *announce* and *indicate* are most fitting to the above context?

> announce:
>
> 1. to tell people something officially, especially about a decision, plans, etc
> 2. to give information about something in a public place, especially through a loudspeaker
> 3. to say something in a loud and/or serious way
>
> indicate:
>
> 1. to show that something is true or exists
> 2. to be a sign of something; to show that something is possible or likely
> 3. to mention something, especially in an indirect way

Comment: Definitions are not mutually exclusive. In this case, **all** of the definitions of _announce_ that are given, a well as **all** of the definitions of _indicate_, are "most fitting to the context".

Comment: Which context are you talking about?

Comment: It's the passage from my first blockquote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In tournament play, the chair umpire *announces* the end of the match with the well-known phrase "Game, set, match" followed by the winning person's or team's name.

All three senses of the word *announce* could be applicable here. But, seeing as to how the "official" is talking about a result, you could say that sense 1 is the best fit.

> It is similarly used in other contexts to *indicate* the winner, often in an argument or a comparison.

"*Game, set and match*" is used, in general, to show that something has been won. Ergo, sense 2 would be the most applicable here.